# Vote to reopen language conversion question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715167/converter-from-delphi-to-php) was being closed as 'not constructive' while I was writing the answer.

I disagree. Given the OPs' rep (15) he may be a newbie faced with the problem op rewriting some Delphi code in PHP. Although no such converter exists, we should definitely give him clues on how to approach his issue. IMO, closing his question is very blunt and unhelpful.

We all had to start somewhere sometime.

Since I do not have the rep to vote to re-open I hope this is the right place do bring that request to peoples' attention (I searched 'reopen question').

FWIW My answer was:
===========
Writing a Delphi -> PHP converter may be technically possible, but it would be an enormous undertaking not worth the effort (extremely small market).
The best you can do is:

- Learn Delphi; since you only need to be able to read it, you can come a long way with running the Delphi code in the IDE, tracing what's happening, inspecting variable values, etc. Simultaneously (or in advance), write small Delphi programs to understand the language basics.
- For specific small parts *where you get stuck*, post them here and ask for help.
  Note the emphasis on *where you get stuck*, a question 'can someone translate this for me' and that does not show effort on your side, will generally not be answered.
- Google 'convert Delphi to PHP' to see examples of people facing the same task, and you will get ideas

===========
[Wow, SO even suggests additional tags to allow this question to be posted!]

Comment: Those sound like excellent comments. The question is asking for a recommendation. Such questions are not constructive and therefore closed as such.

Comment: If you want to answer a question with this "Google 'convert Delphi to PHP' to see examples of people facing the same task, and you will get ideas" then there is something fundamentally wrong with the question. Not to mention that something is wrong with your answer.

Comment: Ok, will put it in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helpfulness is admirable, but even your very positive text is not *an answer to the question* (could you fit its meaning in a comment perhaps?).

And the bigger problem is that the question isn't a good fit for SO, in the way that "What's the PHP for **this specific Delphi thing** ?" or "What's gone wrong with **this specific conversion attempt** ?" would be. So, no reopen vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations are off topic and not constructive for Stack Overflow.

However, a *specific* question, such as: "How do I write this statement of Delphi in PHP" is a valid question.

Comment: Your example is a "please convert x to y for me" and is also very borderline.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: I mean something like "Equivilant of python print in Ruby", or something like that.

Comment: Still not better.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319429/does-ruby-have-something-like-pythons-list-comprehensionsexample

Comment: Okay, I take that back and add a "it depends" (my favorite answer). Your example would be not a good question in my opinion, but the question you linked too is a valid question.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: This is one of those nod invalid, but not very valid either. The "Equivilent" questions get a lot of upvotes because they are useful to future visitors, and as such stay open.